# How can I select a unit in Unity and activate the Canvas on that unit?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, canvas

I'm currently working on a turn based strategie game and I would like to give the player more information for each unit they got.

[image: This is the Hierarchy in Unity...]

The Code is as followed:

```
    public void UnitSelection ()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
        {
            if (hit.collider.tag == "Unit Player 1")
            {
                // How can I select the Canvas from here + Canvas.SetActive(true)
            }
        }
    }
```

I can select a unit with the mouse but I don't know how to get to the Canvas on that GameObject.
Should I work with a tag (isn't that bad practice?) or with other methods?

If you need any more info just write it in a comment. I will add everything you need.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `hit.collider` is the parent object `ArmoredBear_a06` of the `Canvas` you could use [`GetComponentInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentInChildren.html)

```c#
public void UnitSelection ()
{
    if (Physics.Raycast (Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out var hit, Mathf.Infinity))
    {
        var hitCollider = hit.collider;

        if (hitCollider.CompareTag("Unit Player 1"))
        {
            // pass in true to also get inactive or disabled components
            var canvas = hitCollider.GetComponentInChildren<Canvas>(true);

            if(!canvas)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning($"Hitting {hitCollider.name} but no Canvas found in children"); 
                return;
            }

            canvas.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Or alternatively if you anyway know that the Canvas is always the first child you can use [`transform.GetChild`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html)

```c#
public void UnitSelection ()
{
    if (Physics.Raycast (Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out var hit, Mathf.Infinity))
    {
        var hitCollider = hit.collider;

        if (hitCollider.CompareTag("Unit Player 1"))
        {
            var canvas = hitCollider.tramsform.GetChild(0);

            canvas.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a several options to get a canvas.

### First

Get Canvas directly (if collider on the root object) like this:

```
public void UnitSelection ()
{
   Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
   RaycastHit hit;
   if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
   {
      if (hit.collider.tag == "Unit Player 1")
      {
         Canvas canv = hit.collider.GetComponentInChildren<Canvas>(true);
         canv.gameObject.SetActive(true);
         //or you can change only canvas state like this canv.enabled = true;
      }
   }
}
```

### Second:

Or you can attach script to your Unit and change state of Canvas internal:
Part of Bot Script:

```
public class Bot : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject canvasObject;

    public void ChangeStateCanvas(bool state)
    {
        canvasObject.SetActive(state);
    }
}
```

Script with change canvas state:

```
public void UnitSelection ()
{
   Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
   RaycastHit hit;
   if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
   {
      if (hit.collider.tag == "Unit Player 1")
      {
         hit.collider.GetComponent<Bot>().ChangeStateCanvas(true);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: First will fail. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62891235/7111561): You would need to pass in `true` in order to find inactive or disabled components. Second is valid but a bit overkill ;)